# Display Comic Book files on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, php-ziparchive

I'm thinking about creating a webpage and I'm trying to brainstorm some ways to display them in the page.

If i wanted to get dirty and create everything myself, i think i could do it with html5, CSS3, and javascript/jquery. Just do some kind of page buttons with an image tag and maybe get into some more detailed stuff as it comes up (i dont know how i would do zooming and multiple pages).

But wahat i really want to know is if there is already some way to do this? I've looked around for a bit and cant seem to find any sort of plugin that would read a cbz file or display an set of images with the 'e-reader' type of tools in mind. Just wondering if anyone knows of anything?

Thanks

Comment: So far as I can tell, no such thing exists. You could do this quite easily with a server-side component to extract the image files from the CBZ archive, but if you intended it to be entirely client-side you'd have a lot of work on your hands.

Comment: Yes, i think server side extraction would be pretty necessary. Even for a single CBR file. I assume its pretty simple to unzip/unrar the archive file and hand the client the images. I dont have much experience with creating server side stuff at the moment, but definitely something im up for.

Comment: If you wanted to keep it entirely client side (and then package it up as a Chrome app/other browser extension), you could implement it using the [File API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) - other than that I'm not sure. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use an online reader for a long time so I started an experiment to build one myself a while back: [netcomix](https://github.com/JohnMunsch/netcomix)

It's open source so you can see if you find anything appealing in what I did. I figured I'd do all the real UI work client side with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and the server was strictly responsible for acting as a service (for example, to supply a list of comics or a list of all the pages in a particular issue) and serving up the individual JPG/PNG/GIF files. That compartmentalized things nicely and I was very pleased with how jQuery BBQ gave me a history that I could back through even though I stayed on one page the whole time.

Now if I were to do the same experiment again, I'd use Backbone.js to give some structure to the client side and obviously it needs a lot of love because the server side really does nothing at the moment. Early versions were strictly hard coded although I started putting in some simple SQL stuff in there in the latest version. It's nothing more than an experiment though and should be treated as such. It's there for ideas and little else. If you find it interesting and want some more ideas contact me and I'll be happy to let you know all my wacky ideas for such a program.

Comment: I think this is what i was going for. As mentioned by Jim O'Brien, i think the server could simply extract the image files and like you said return it to the client with handles what to do with them. I will take a look at your experiment, but it sounds like its in the same vein as what i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But web technologies have gotten better in the last few years. There are several comic book readers that can work in the browser using pure HTML and JavaScript. I wrote one called: http://comic-book-reader.com .

If you want to see a very simple example of how to read CBR and CBZ files in the browser. You should check out http://workhorsy.github.io/uncompress.js/examples/simple/index.html which uses the JavaScript library https://github.com/workhorsy/uncompress.js